# Check out all these items!

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, knowledge, video-games

*Words can’t even **begin** to describe how clueless I am! This is all meaningless! Ugh, why does it feel like I’m in a video game or something?*

> What? Savage rap ends Instagram!
>   Flame the most idiotic cretins
>   Covertly slap opponents around - it’s an essential thing
>   Troll punches you - get rid of it for me!
>   Defamation closely following crude welcome - it’s damaging
>   Frustrating experience? Turn to flimsy guy
>   Cry and eject essential fluid
>   Young, brainwashed, and quiet leaders finally fail
>      <sub><sub><sub>Call (577) 710-7690 for a *lengthy* rant about these items!</sub></sub></sub>

**What am I actually trying to describe?**

---

**HINT 1:** (Moved to the main body of the puzzle)

**HINT 2:** (Moved to the main body of the puzzle)

**HINT 3:**

> Fine, I’ll try to be less cryptic here. First of all, I'm not actually angry at anything - sorry if I misled you there! Second, the video game I’m talking about is a quietly good broken car without its hood (7). Does that help?

**HINT 4:** (major spoiler)

> Each line is *not* a sensationalized news headline but rather a cryptic clue without the definition or enumeration. The enumerations can be found somewhere in the puzzle body. And in place of the definitions, each CC relates to a common theme based on the video game and parts of the flavortext and title.

Comment: Apparently my very carefully constructed clickbait title wasn’t enough to grab people’s attention...

Comment: Well, I've noticed it, but I haven't solved anything yet (though I have some idea what is going on).

Comment: The first line rot13(vf na nantenz bs "cerjnfu qrinfgngvat nantenzf") but that's all I got for tonight...

Comment: @MetaZen ha, that’s a nice find! But it was unintentional, so try looking elsewhere

Comment: All right, it's been a week, and no significant progress besides jafe's (partial) identification of the mechanism has been made so far. Hoping that this bounty, albeit a small amount, will encourage more participation :)

Comment: why is this not tagged as cryptic crossword clues?

Comment: @KateGregory It appears that was intended to be part of the enigmatic puzzle was to determine that they were cryptic crossword clues.

Comment: Well, I don't like it. I hate cryptic clues and ignore the tag. It wasn't exactly hidden that these were such: I recognized them immediately and I hate them. We should tag accurately and not leave off tags just because you want people to guess what kind of puzzle it is.

Comment: @KateGregory Like LeppyR64 said, the intent was to figure out the main mechanism, then use that mechanism to find the answer to the question. But as you’ve figured out yourself, the mechanism isn’t that well hidden, so the puzzle doesn’t really count as enigmatic (unless I’m mistaken about how that tag works here on this SE). Thanks for your comment!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Hint 3:

> *Quietly good broken car without its hood* (7)
>  This is P (musical marking for piano = quietly) + OK (good) + (L)EMON (broken car without its hood) = **POKEMON**

Hint 4:

> The phone number at the bottom hides the enumerations of the cryptic clues.

The clues:

> *What? Savage rap ends Instagram!* (5)
>  - (WHA)T + (SAVAG)E + (RA)P + IG = **TEPIG**
>
>  *Flame the most idiotic cretins* (7)
>  - TORCH (flame) + I(DIOTIC) + C(RETINS) = **TORCHIC**<sup>1</sup>
>
>  *Covertly slap opponents around - it’s an essential thing* (7)
>  - (sla)P OPP(onents) + OIL< (from "essential oil") = **POPPLIO**
>
>  *Troll punches you - get rid of it for me!* (7)
>  - PUNCHES* -U (you) +I (me) = **CHESPIN**<sup>1</sup>
>
>  *Defamation closely following crude welcome - it’s damaging* (10)
>  - C(RUDE) + HARM (damaging) + (SL)ANDER = **CHARMANDER**<sup>1</sup>
>
>  *Frustrating experience? Turn to flimsy guy* (7)
>  - I suppose this is RUT< + TWIG = **TURTWIG**?<sup>1</sup> Does "twig" mean "flimsy guy"?
>
>  *Cry and eject essential fluid* (6)
>  - SOB + B(I)LE = **SOBBLE**
>
>  *Young, brainwashed, and quiet leaders finally fail* (9)
>  - This is CY (Cy Young) + AND* + QU(IET) + (FA)IL = **CYNDAQUIL**
>
>  <sup>1</sup> (with help from LeppyR64 in the comments)

The theme could be

> One [starter Pokémon](https://pokemon.fandom.com/wiki/Starter_Pok%C3%A9mon) from each generation? (found by LeppyR64)

Comment: I can’t believe it... you’re on the right track! If you’re stuck, then take a closer look at the tags and flavortext

Comment: That anti-climatic twist at the end xD

Comment: Had to award the bounty to this answer since it was going to expire, but I’ve made massive changes to the puzzle to hopefully make it clearer what’s going on and how to proceed

Comment: @PiIsNot3 Thanks! Hoping to earn it retroactively by cracking this...

Comment: Oooh.  Getting the Gen 8 in there.

Comment: Ah, sorry about the second to last clue. In fact, rot13(“rwrpg rffragvny” jnf fhccbfrq gb or na vaqvpngbe sbe erzbivat cneg bs gur zvqqyr bs “ovyr,” ohg fvapr gurer’f gjb yrggref va gur zvqqyr bs gung jbeq, vg qbrfa’g ernyyl jbex.)

Comment: @LeppyR64 Maybe it's one of each? Hmm...

Comment: @PiIsNot3 Oh, I see. I thought it could be either "myself" (the most important person) or "number one" (in Roman numerals), but neither seemed exactly kosher as an explanation...

Comment: They're all Starters too.  That leaves Turtwig and Charmander as guaranteeds.  Gen 4 is either Torchic or Treecko, Gen 6 is Chespin or Froakie.

Comment: @LeppyR64 That's very helpful. Any idea how to get Chespin or Froakie out of the last one? I suppose we're supposed to remove "it" from some word and add "me" or maybe "i" instead? Punches could be "h**it**s", or troll could be "ba**it**", but neither seems to work toward one of the expected answers...

Comment: Troll punches = (ches)(pun)... get rid of (u)for me (i)... Chespin

Comment: @LeppyR64 Ah, I see now. Nice!

Comment: All the solutions are right! For the "flimsy guy" clue, I'm using [this definition](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=twig) of the word, though I'm not sure how common it really is. The theme is also correct, and the bolded word in the  flavortext should make more sense now. That leaves just the title of the puzzle...